# What is the meaning of this makefile syntax %IDLINC%

Tags: makefile, gfortran

I am trying to build a library for IDL however I am running into a lot of troubles. I believe understanding this line of syntax could help lead me to solve my bigger problems.

From what I know. The source code is written in fortran (I think?). There is the where the syntax first appears:

```
FOPTIONS_SHARED_win64_mingw=-I%IDLINC% -fno-second-underscore -static
```

I believe this FOPTIONS variable plays in a role in the building of a shared library file (.dll). What does this line mean? In particular, what exactly is %IDLINC% ?(double percent signs) I see it appear quite a bit in the warning messages.

And here is a little snippet of the compile/link code from the makefile which uses the FOPTIONS variable:

```
all.help:
@more $(HELPDIR)/Help.all

all: all.$(OS).$(ENV)

all..:
echo "Missing OS and ENV variables"

all.linux32.intel32: all.build
all.linux32.gnu32: all.build
all.linux32.pgi32: all.build
all.linux64.intel32: all.build
all.linux64.intel64: all.build
all.linux64.gnu32: all.build
all.linux64.gnu64: all.build
all.linux64.pgi64: all.build
all.linux64.gfortran64: all.build
all.win32.cygwin32: all.build
all.win64.cygwin64: all.build
all.win32.mingw: all.build
all.win64.mingw: all.build
all.mach.gnu32: all.build
all.sunos.sparc32: all.build
all.sunos.sparc64: all.build
all.sunos.gnu32: all.build
all.sunos.gnu64: all.build


all.build: version.fortran ntime_max
    @cd $(SOURCEDIR); \
cp wrappers_$(WRAPPER_$(OS)_$(ENV)).inc wrappers.inc;\
echo "Building non-sharable object \
onera_desp_lib_$(LIBNAME_$(OS)_$(ENV)).$(NONSHAREDEXT_$(OS))"; \
$(FC_$(OS)_$(ENV)) $(FOPTIONS_NONSHARED_$(OS)_$(ENV)) *.f;\
$(AR) $(AROPTIONS_$(OS)) liboneradesp_$(LIBNAME_$(OS)_$(ENV)).$(NONSHAREDEXT_$(OS)) *.o;\
$(RANLIB) liboneradesp_$(LIBNAME_$(OS)_$(ENV)).$(NONSHAREDEXT_$(OS));\
echo "non-sharable object built";\
echo "";\
echo "Building sharable object \
onera_desp_lib_$(LIBNAME_$(OS)_$(ENV)).$(SHAREDEXT_$(OS))"; \
$(FC_$(OS)_$(ENV)) $(FOPTIONS_SHARED_$(OS)_$(ENV)) $(PIC_$(OS)_$(ENV)) -o 
onera_desp_lib_$(LIBNAME_$(OS)_$(ENV)).$(SHAREDEXT_$(OS)) \
*.f $(LDOPTIONS_$(OS)_$(ENV));\
echo "sharable object built";\
echo "";\
echo "Building sequence achieved";
```

Any help would be greatly appreicated! I am a complete beginner with Makefiles.

Comment: It appears to be an option to be passed to the Fortan compiler. If you were invoking the compiler on the command line, you would type that option into the command line; when you use this makefile, Make does the same thing on your behalf. The string `%IDLINC%` means nothing to Make, it is just something it passes to the compiler because the makefile tells it to.

Comment: As @Beta says that means nothing to make.  However, often text like `%FOO%` or `@FOO@` is used in a file that is intended to be processed before use, and that processing is supposed to replace that text with a computed value.  What's the name of the makefile that contains this token?  Does it end with `.in` for example?  Often `.in` files are intended to be run through another command to replace these tokens and write out a file without the `.in` extension.  Ultimately this has nothing to do with make itself: you'll have to read the docs for the build system you're using.

Comment: *"I see it appear quite a bit in the warning messages."* - what warning messages?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the explaination. I was loosing my mind over what %% meant in makefiles. This helps alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%IDLINC%` isn't makefile syntax, it's MS-DOS syntax. Variable substitution to be precise. The reason you see this in the warnings is because Make prints each command after its own pass of substitutions. Then it passes the command to the shell (MS-DOS) for actual execution, at which point IDLINC is substituted by that shell.

Since prefixed by `-I` in `-I%IDLINC%` I assume the variable is meant to hold the path to the IDL headers.

Comment: Thank you for this explaination. This helps a lot in understanding what is going on in this makefile.